# How can I reset crime counts in the General Stats screen?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Are there any working console commands for this? I've tried `modpcmiscstat` but it results in a crash to the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a command like this

```
player.setcrimegold XXX <faction id>
```

For general stats the command is:

```
modpcmiscstat (stat) (integer)
```

But the CTD bug you have is common, people are asking about it and at present there isn’t a fix. http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61023778